# Dry Hopping without a bag

Tags: dry-hop

I'll have about 1/2 an ounce of leftover Cascade hop pellets when I finish my boil. I was thinking that I would save them and throw them in the secondary, but I don't have a bag.

Will I get much aroma out of just throwing the pellets in by themselves without a bag?

Comment: What's the volume? 5 gallons?

Comment: You could have also just put them in the boil at flameout.

Comment: @Dean Brundage Yes, the volume is 5 gallons. @brewchez I also added some hops at late boil for aroma, but I've never done dry hopping, so I wanted to try it out for fun. I think I am going to try it without a bag this time, and then do it with a bag next time and maybe I'll notice a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.  I dry-hopped my last brew by just dropping the pellets into the carboy and it had a great aroma.  The pellets broke up and sunk and then I just racked without disturbing the sediment.

Answer (score 1):

## Probably

It'll give your beer a nice little aroma boost.

See also: [Pellet Hops spilled out of bag in secondary. Advice?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/717/pellet-hops-spilled-out-of-bag-in-secondary-advice)